# Build message - Unknown compiler version, for dealii-4.8.1 library on visual studios

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, build, cmake, error-messaging

My build output gives many error messages of:

"Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results"

...when attempting to build INSTALL for the dealii-8.4.1 library (open source, finite element library - graphics library) on Visual studios 14.0 (v 2015) c++.

A portion of the build is shown below.

Can anyone advise on what this means? and how to: "run the configure tests and report the results?" I Configured dealii-8.4.1 using cmake to start with.

Using deal.II on native Windows (dealii webpage and instructions)
https://github.com/dealii/dealii/wiki/Windows

PORTION OF BUILD OUTPUT on Visual Studios
44>  vector_tools_point_value.cc
44>  Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results
44>C:\dealii-8.4.1\source\numerics\vector_tools_point_value.cc(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'vector_tools_point_value.inst': No such file or directory
44>  vector_tools_point_gradient.cc
44>  Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results
44>C:\dealii-8.4.1\source\numerics\vector_tools_point_gradient.cc(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'vector_tools_point_gradient.inst': No such file or directory
44>  vector_tools_project.cc
44>  Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results
44>C:\dealii-8.4.1\source\numerics\vector_tools_project.cc(22): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'vector_tools_project.inst': No such file or directory
44>  vector_tools_rhs.cc
44>  Unknown compiler version - please run the configure tests and report the results
44>C:\dealii-8.4.1\source\numerics\vector_tools_rhs.cc(83): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'vector_tools_rhs.inst': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be due to deal.II on native Windows, as for the windows version it states:

"Warning: please be aware that the following is experimental and you will likely encounter bugs in compilers and deal.II itself. Only continue if you are willing to experiment."
https://github.com/dealii/dealii/wiki/Windows

And: "deal.II is mostly developed on Linux using the GCC compiler."
http://www.dealii.org/8.4.1/readme.html

So it may be better to install Linux (Ubuntu) to see if that solves it.